# How to get Line-s from Canvas Children in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, controls, line

I'm trying to delete some lines I have drawn on my canvas, and my idea was to use the coordinates of the Line controls from `Canvas.Children`.

My initial code looked like this:

```
    var ax = Mouse.GetPosition(Canvas).X;
    int mx1 = (int)ax - (eraserSize / 2);
    int mx2 = (int)ax + (eraserSize / 2);
    var ay = Mouse.GetPosition(Canvas).Y;
    int my1 = (int)ay - (eraserSize / 2);
    int my2 = (int)ay + (eraserSize / 2);

foreach(Line l in Canvas.Children)
{
    if((l.X1 < mx1 && lX2 > mx2) && (l.Y1 < my1 && lY2 > my2))
    {
        Canvas.Children.Remove(l);
    }
}
```

But of course it doesn't work since there are other controls that it cannot cast to Line.

I tried using `if(l.Name == "LineName")` to put these in a `Line[]` or `Control[]` but nothing works, and I'm not sure what else to try, other then just painting over it...

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you create a proper ViewModel and use proper DataBinding and proper DataTemplates to do all this instead of putting everything directly in the UI manually thru procedural code. Your code should not depend on the state of UI elements in the Visual Tree.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with how to check for types in C#. That aside, the answer is `foreach ( Line l in Canvas.Children.Where( c => c is Line ) )`

Comment: @StevenJeuris except it's really better to say `Canvas.Children.OfType<Line>()`

Comment: @HighCore Oops, well that was why it was a quick comment and not an answer. ;p

Comment: Thanks, I'm still learning C# as an autodidact, and i just now moved over to WPF from Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(var child in Canvas.Children)
{
    var l = child as Line;
    if(l != null && (l.X1 < mx1 && lX2 > mx2) && (l.Y1 < my1 && lY2 > my2))
    {
        // You can't remove item from collection you enumerate thru
        // Canvas.Children.Remove(l);
        LinesToDelete.Add(l);
    }
}
```

Than you can simple remove all lines that got to LinesToDelete

Comment: As in the comments on the question itself, the if check can be removed by simply querying only for lines through `Canvas.Children.OfType<Line>()`.